# Creating an abstract base class for handling different type of enums

Tags: java, enums

Currently I have several enums defined over several classes. They all look similar to the one shown below:

```
public class ApaMessage {
  private String apaMessage;
  private final int FIXED_LENGTH_SIZE=39;


  public enum ApaFields {
    FIELD1(ApaUtils.ApaFieldTypes.POSITION_BASED, null, "field1", 2, 3, false, false),
    private final ApaUtils.ApaFieldTypes type;
    private final String ApaName;
    private final String jsonName;
    private final int start;
    private final int finish;
    private boolean required = false;
    private boolean withDelimiter = false;

ApaFields(ApaUtils.ApaFieldTypes type, String ApaName, String jsonName, int start, int finish, boolean required, boolean withDelimiter) {
      this.type = type;
      this.ApaName = ApaName;
      this.jsonName = jsonName;
      this.start = start;
      this.finish = finish;
      this.required = required;
      this.withDelimiter = withDelimiter;
    }
  }
```

There is also a method defined in ApaMessage:

```
private HashMap<String,Object> getApaJsonFieldsAndValues() {
    HashMap<String, Object> jsonApaData = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    for (ApaFields field : ApaFields.values()) {
      jsonApaData.put(field.jsonName, getApaFieldValue(field));  
    }
    return jsonApaData;
  }
```

The problem is although there isn't a lot of code, I will soon have 10-20 of these enums. I would like to create an abstract base class where the HashMap method, and other similar methods can be part of. The base class should accept an ApaFields enum and other enums and do what the getApaJsonFieldsAndValues does. The problem is, how can the base class access the passed enum values and the internal fields such as jsonName to do the loop?

I have tried different approaches but the main problem is that the base class cannot seem to access the values. Is there any way around this? Alternatively, is there a better approach? Thanks

EDIT:

Basically I would like something like this in the base class. Note the below doesn't compile.

public abstract class ApaRequestMessage {

```
    private Class<? extends Enum<?>> apaRequestMessageFields;
    private String apaMessage;
    public <T extends Enum<T>> void ApaRequest(Object apaRequestFields,  String apaMessage) {  

        apaRequestMessageFields = (Class<? extends Enum<?>>) apaRequestFields;
        this.apaMessage = apaMessage;      
        for  (Field field: apaRequestMessageFields.values()) {
            //this doesn't work because it cannot access the values of apaRequestMessageFields                
        }
    }
}
```

And then call the base method as follows, although not sure if this is correct, where ApaFields is the inner enum defined above.

```
 ApaRequest(ApaFields.class, somestringmessage);
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: Unless your example is misleading, I think you shouldn't be using inner enumerations. I would either use an externally defined enumeration holding all FIELDS, or declare a single FIELD as a private field on each class

Comment: Maybe your enums should implement a common interface and you work only with that interface in the method that return the hash map.

Answer (score 0):

I came across something similar when trying to define a db schema using enums as columns in the table. I eventually took this route.

Define a base class with sufficient generic signature to ensure the enum is properly built.

```
public class Table<Column extends Enum<? extends Column>> {
    // Name of the table.

    protected final String tableName;
    // All of the columns in the table. This is actually an EnumSet so very efficient.
    protected final Set<Column> columns;

    /**
     * The base interface for all Column enums.
     */
    public interface Columns {

        // What type does it have in the database?
        public Type getType();
    }

    // Small list of database types.
    public enum Type {
        String, Number, Date;
    }

    public Table(String tableName,
            Set<Column> columns) {
        this.tableName = tableName;
        this.columns = columns;
    }

}
```

Now extend this for each table - here is a simple `VersionTable`:

```
public class VersionTable extends Table<VersionTable.Column> {

  public enum Column implements Table.Columns {
    Version(Table.Type.String),
    ReleaseDate(Table.Type.Date);

    final Table.Type type;

    Column(Table.Type type) {
      this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public Type getType() {
      return type;
    }
  }

  public VersionTable() {
    super("Versions", EnumSet.allOf(Column.class));
  }
}
```

Now you have all of the core functionality in the base class and all the sub-classes need to do is implement the interface on the `enum`.

I realise this does not address the issue of duplicated bolierplate code in all of your enums but it does move *alomst* all of it elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the help, one question though,  how do you loop over the Column enum in Table class and get hold of all the values in Column?  Essentially that is my big issue. I.e. how do you do  for (Column field : Column.values()) {} The only thing accessible is getEnumConstants() and not the actual values.

Comment: That solution is very verbose. You could use some code generator that will parse some XML or SQL format to produce Java code.

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti - The `Table` parent class is populated with a local final `Set<Column> columns;` at construction time. This can be iterated simply. As they all implement `Columns` they can be manipllated in a common fashion.